# expected '0th' to equal '0'

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

```
function numberToOrdinal(i) {
    var j = i % 10,
    k = i % 100;
    if (j == 0 && k == 100) {
        return '0th';
    }
    if (j == 1 && k != 11) {
        return i + "st";
    }
    if (j == 2 && k != 12) {
        return i + "nd";
    }
    if (j == 3 && k != 13) {
        return i + "rd";
    }
    return i + "th";
}
```

It's not passing this test, what's wrong?

*should handle single digits
expected '0th' to equal '0'*

Comment: Well, `numberToOrdinal(0)` will correctly enter the `return` statement... Is the problem that you're expecting `0` back, rather than `0th`? The condition will never be entered for anything other than `0` though...

Comment: Your code returns `0th` when called with `0` as the argument ... however not from `if (j == 0 && k == 100)` - which can never be true

Comment: seems you want `if (i == 0) {
return '0';
}` --- and remove that nonsensical (and never true) `if (j == 0 && k == 100) {`

Comment: Even I use 0 as a string alone, it still brings the same error.

Comment: What's the test?

Comment: Btw, `k` will never be 100, because `i % 100` will always be a number between 0 and 99. So the first if-statement will never be true, but this shouldn't have an impact on the result as you default on `i + "th"` anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you gonna devide a unknown input you wanna check if the input given might be zero. Else there might be an devisionbyzero exception thrown.

```js
function numberToOrdinal(i) {
 if(i === 0){ // since we devide i we wanna check if it might be zero. 
  return i ;
 }
 var j = i % 10,
 k = i % 100;
 //if (j == 0 && k == 100) { didnt seem to be doing anything
    //return '0th';
 //}
 if (j == 1 && k != 11) {
  return i + "st";
 }
 if (j == 2 && k != 12) {
  return i + "nd";
 }
 if (j == 3 && k != 13) {
  return i + "rd";
 }
 return i + "th";
}
console.log(numberToOrdinal(0));
```

Comment: I have to say it's a bit weird that you accept an answer that doesn't fix your problem. It's really hard to give a correct answer if you don't show us what the test looks like.

Answer (score 0):

you could just change these lines

```js
if (j == 0 && k == 100) {
return '0th';
}
```

to be

```js
if (i == 0) {
return i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your function to return 0 when 0 is passed to the function, you will need to enter a condition to handle that, such as:

```
if (i === 0) {
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: should handle single digits expected '0th' to equal '0'

Comment: thats the error above, i need to pass some hidden unit test

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter another condition to handle it

```
function numberToOrdinal(i) {
    var j = i % 10,
        k = i % 100;

    if (i === 0) {
        return i;
    }

    if (j == 1 && k != 11) {
        return `${i}st`;
    }

    if (j == 2 && k != 12) {
        return `${i}nd`;
    }

    if (j == 3 && k != 13) {
        return `${i}rd`;
    }
    return `${i}th`;
}
```